# Match columns from two dataframes and filter on the value of another columns

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have two dataframes with the same number of columns but different number of rows:

```
colA colB colC colD
xxx  303  200  A
yyy  111  20   B
zzz  24  188   C
```

I need to match `colA` from `df1` to `colA` from `df2` and select only the rows where `df1$colB - df2$colC <= 2000`

I tried to do the for loop but it didn't work:

```
for (i in nrow(df1)) {
    for (j in nrow(df2)) {
        df3 <- subset(merge(df2[j,], df1[i,], by="row.names", all=T), df2$colA[j] == df1$colA[i] && (df1$colB[i] - df2$colC[j]) <= abs(2000))
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It doesn't give me any error but the new dataframe is empty.

Comment: Probably something like `dfNew <- merge(df1, df2[c("colA", "colC"), by="colA"]); dfNew <- dfNew[(dfNew$colB - dfNew$colC) <= 2000, ]` from the description.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If `dplyr` is an option, try this:

```
df1 %>%
    inner_join(df2, by = "colA") %>%
    filter(abs(colB.x - colC.y) <= 2000)
```

This will give you a frame with columns
`colA, colB.x, colC.x, colD.x, colB.y, colC.y, colD.y`
where the .x are from df1 and the .y are from df2.
Also note that `b - a <= abs(2000)` is likely supposed to mean `abs(b - a) <= 2000`